# useState React Nativo

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks

Estou começando no React Native e estou travado em um problema com `useState`, tenho uma api que me retorna esse dados:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1c0e5f9e-4228-4bef-a639-301f27b20c7e",
        "description": "*******",
        "value": "650",
        "date": "2023-01-26T00:00:00.000Z",
        "type": true,
        "create_at": "2023-01-26T13:41:25.536Z",
        "modified_at": "2023-01-26T14:02:39.166Z",
        "delete_at": null,
        "categories_id": "10f27779-ce30-49d3-9db4-9867d2987364"
    },
    {
        "id": "a40716ae-12d4-49df-9ec2-56a58773f164",
        "description": "******",
        "value": "320",
        "date": "2023-01-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "type": true,
        "create_at": "2023-01-26T20:13:58.984Z",
        "modified_at": "2023-01-26T20:15:35.383Z",
        "delete_at": null,
        "categories_id": "1a60f837-fc4b-49c0-947a-1c8c007cb3b3"
    }
]
```

e no meu aplicativo React Native estou fazendo essa requisição:

```
const [saldo, setSaldo] = useState(0);
const [gastos, setGastos] = useState(0);
const [moviments, setMoviments] = useState([]);

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await api.get("/moviments");
    setMoviments(response.data);
    response.data.map(item => {
      if (item.type === true) {
        setSaldo(saldo + parseFloat(item.value));
      } else {
        setGastos(gastos + parseFloat(item.value));
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert("Ops", "Não foi possível carregar as ultimas movimentações")
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}
```

após pegar o retorno da API, estou tentando somar os campos `value` utilizando o map e o setState, mas o valor do state `saldo` não está saindo correto.

é como se o `setSaldo(saldo + parseFloat(item.value))` não estivesse alterando corretamente o valor do state `saldo`

Comment: tente isso: `setSaldo(saldo + parseFloat(item.value));` Coloque isso => `setSaldo(saldo => saldo + parseFloat(item.value));`

Comment: @CmteCardeal funcionou, obrigado, quer colocar como resposta para eu marcar ?